# Django - Reportlab - No muestra imagen en PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, archivo, canvas

No muestra la imagen (`logo.png`) en REPORTLAB al generar el PDF:

```
def some_view(request):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
    archivo_imagen = 'img/logo.png'
    p.drawImage(archivo_imagen, 40, 750, 120, 90,preserveAspectRatio=True)
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    buffer.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='incidencias.pdf')
```

La base de `static` está configurada. Por ejemplo se muestra imagen en Django, (no en PDF, sino en web) si hago esto:

```
<img sourc="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Se debe añadir en la ruta completa añadiendo setting.BASE_DIR e importante: importar settings ya que la base o ruta de las imágenes está indicado en BASE_DIR (de settings)

Código correcto:

```
archivo_imagen = settings.BASE_DIR+'/blog/static/img/logo.png'
p.drawImage(archivo_imagen, 40, 750, 120, 90,preserveAspectRatio=True)
```

Quedando el código completo así:

```
from django.conf import settings
import reportlab
import io
from django.http import FileResponse
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def some_view(request):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
    archivo_imagen = settings.BASE_DIR+'/blog/static/img/logo.png'
    p.drawImage(archivo_imagen, 40, 750, 120, 90,preserveAspectRatio=True)
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    buffer.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='incidencias.pdf')
```